# Script to move pictures

Tags: bash, scripts

How can I write a script that will move all `.png .svg .gif` files from `/home/eric/Desktop` to `/usr/share/icons`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follows

> `#!/bin/sh`
>
> `gksu mv /home/eric/Desktop/*.png /usr/share/icons & mv /home/eric/Desktop/*.svg /usr/share/icons & mv /home/eric/Desktop/*.gif /usr/share/icons & exit`

*I'm not a bash expert - but this should work. if it doesn't there is no warranty with my answer :P*

Comment: works with some modification

Comment: That's an sh script, not a bash script, and there's no point in running the `mv`s in parallel. I'd make a bash-script that does `shopt -s extglob` and then `mv ~eric/Desktop/*.@(png|svg|gif) /usr/share/icons/`

Comment: told you I'm no expert :P

Comment: i'd use 'sudo' instead of 'gksu' in a shell script. im no expert either.

Comment: sudo is good, but gksu is safer, and graphical

Comment: `&` backgrounds the command, so these `mv` comments run in parallel. `geirha` command is much better. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: @Roland Taylor: `gksu` is safer than `sudo`? Reference please, last I read it was just a wrapper for `sudo`.

Comment: @sorry l0b0 I don't have have the link to hand (and I'm not searching). If you want to find out, google is at hand. Or DuckDuckGo... or speculation... etc.

Answer (score 3):

bash can handle this easily:

```
mv /home/eric/Desktop/*.{png,svg,gif} /usr/share/icons
```

Use `sudo mv ...` if  you don't have permission to write into /usr/share/icons.

Comment: There ya go, pushed you over 3k.

Comment: I shall only use my powers for evil...

Comment: Needs a maniacal laugh at the end of that comment, ala Dr. Evil from Austin Powers or something 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `find`? This worked for me:

```
find ./  -maxdepth 1 \( -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.gif" -o -iname "*.svg" \) -ok cp {} /tmp/ \;
```

You want to `mv` not `cp`, and your destination is `/usr/share/icons` not `/tmp` but you can run this from the command line or a shell script.

`-iname` is case insensitive, `-name` would be case sensitive. Tweak the `-maxdepth` to your liking, and/or pull of the `-ok` clause to just see what it is coming up with.