# Move images from sub-folders into new sub-folders

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, directory

I have a folder composed of `M` several sub-folders, each of them containing some text files and `N` images (`*.png`)

This is what the tree looks like:

```
/parent/
  /sub-folder1/
   /data1.dat
   /data2.dat
   /image1.png
   /image2.png
   ...
   /imageN.png
 /sub-folder2/
   /data1.dat
   /data2.dat
   /image1.png
   /image2.png
   ...
   /imageN.png
 ...
 /sub-folderM/
   /data1.dat
   /data2.dat
   /image1.png
   /image2.png
   ...
   /imageN.png
```

notice that all images in each sub-folder are named the same (ie: `image1.png, ..., imageN.png`)

What I need is to move **only the images** into a new parent folder (say `parent2`), while replicating the sub-folder structure. After the moving is done the new parent folder should look like this:

```
/parent2/
  /sub-folder1/
   /image1.png
   /image2.png
   ...
   /imageN.png
 /sub-folder2/
   /image1.png
   /image2.png
   ...
   /imageN.png
 ...
 /sub-folderM/
   /image1.png
   /image2.png
   ...
   /imageN.png
```

(ie: only images and respecting the same sub-folders structure)

and the original `parent` folder should look like:

```
/parent/
  /sub-folder1/
   /data1.dat
   /data2.dat
 /sub-folder2/
   /data1.dat
   /data2.dat
 ...
 /sub-folderM/
   /data1.dat
   /data2.dat
```

(ie: images moved out)

I've seen some examples of scripts that can move all filed into a new folder ([Shell script to move all files from subfolders to parent folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146634/shell-script-to-move-all-files-from-subfolders-to-parent-folder)) or some that can move only images ([Script to move pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30399/script-to-move-pictures)) but I haven't found one that would do so while *respecting the sub-folders tree*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using rsync:

```
rsync -av --include="*/"  --include='*.png' --exclude='*' parent1 parent2
```

this creates directory parent2 and copies all files with .png extension with subdirectory structure to it.
explanation

- -v verbose to see whats copied
- -a archive mode (copy subdirectories with same ownership, permissions  etc.)
- --include '*/' --include='*.png' include .png ending files  first part is to create subdirectories
- --exclude='*' exclude all other files
  for more info see rsync man page

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy parent1 to parent2
2. Remove dat files from parent2 subdirectories
3. Remove png files from parent1 subdirectories

> ```
> $ cp -r parent1/ parent2
> $ rm parent2/*/*.dat
> $ rm parent1/*/*.png
> ```